# Is there a website where you can search court cases by keywords?

Tags: legal-research

By this I mean a site where you type certain keywords and it narrows down does a query of all court cases that have those keywords.

Comment: I do't know of any such site for all US cases, let alone world wide. What jurisdiction did you have in mind?

Comment: Yes, but they aren't free.

Answer (score 2):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

Free:

[BAILII](https://www.bailii.org/)

Paid:

[Westlaw UK](https://uk.westlaw.com)

[LexisNexis](https://www.lexisnexis.co.uk/)

Answer (score 0):

For the United States, I'd recommend the following:

- [CourtListener](https://www.courtlistener.com/)
- [Justia](https://www.justia.com/)
- [CaseText](https://casetext.com/)

Answer (score 0):

For [australia](/questions/tagged/australia) [austlii.edu.au](http://austlii.edu.au) has all jurisdictions.

Answer (score 0):

For [slovakia](/questions/tagged/slovakia), there is a corpus of [court decisions](https://www.juls.savba.sk/justicecorp.html). Although primarily targeted for linguistic research, it is exactly this.